# Implementing the strategy pattern. Do I have to 'new up' everytime?

Tags: c#, strategy-pattern

I am trying to implement the [strategy pattern.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) Here is part of my implementation:

```
public List<string> GetOrderedEmployeeNames(IOrderByStrategy strategy)
{
   return GetEmployeeFullNames().OrderBy(strategy.Order);
}
```

now every time I call this function I have to write:

```
var employees = GetOrderedEmployeeNames(new OrderByFamilyName());
```

Is 'new-ing up' the strategy every time the right way or am I implementing this incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily, although it's probably not hurting anything to create objects as I'm assuming they're mostly methods and don't hold a lot of data.

Some alternatives:

- Implement a `StrategyFactory` that either creates new instances or hold references to flyweights (small objects that are indexed by some key, like a string)
- Implement the strategies as singletons, but that may be more overhead than you need if there are a lot of strategies.

Comment: yeah they are just Expression<Func<string, bool>>'s

Answer (score 7):

If the class that implements `IOrderByStrategy` doesn't have any state (i.e. behaves the same every time) then you might as well store it in a field somewhere to save having to re-`new` it.

That said, `new` is a very efficient operation and if you're not calling it in a tight loop, it may be simpler to keep doing what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can store a property if the strategy will have same behavior. If not, you can create object with parameters.

```
    private IOrderByStrategy orderByStrategy;
    public IOrderByStrategy OrderByStrategy
    {
         get
         {
            if(orderByStrategy != null)
               return orderByStrategy;
            else
               return new OrderByStrategy();
         }
    }
var employees = GetOrderedEmployeeNames(OrderByStrategy);
```

Second situation:

```
var employees = GetOrderedEmployeeNames(new OrderByFamilyName("familyname","DESC"));
```